# Select a lot of columns from two different tables using hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables A & B. They share some columns. I want to select the common part of these two tables.

I know the following code is ok:

```
select col1, col2, ..., colN from A
union all
select col1, col2, ..., colN from B
```

However, I think the code is not good enough because I write `col1, col2, ..., colN` twice. It will be painful if I want to update the selected columns.

Does anybody have any other suggestion?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps can `UNION CORRESPONDING BY` save you some typing.)

Comment: Hive, actually.

Comment: I have no Hive knowledge at all. You can try my answer below and see if it works.

Comment: It does't work. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from A
union all CORRESPONDING BY (col1, col2, ..., colN)
select * from B
```

ANSI/ISO SQL-2016, Feature F301, CORRESPONDING in query expressions.